# Extremely low FPS, what profiling application should I use to find performance issues?

Tags: c#, performance, xna, profiling

I'm creating an XNA game and am getting an unexpected result, extremely low FPS (About 2-12 fps). What program should I use to test performance and track down what is slowing it down?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using [SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune)?

You could also use [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure sections manually.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it and further found that my culling method wasnt working and was drawing alot offscreen, restred to almost 30 fps now (30 fps is normal for my craptop)

Answer (score 7):

Okay, let me bring my personal experience with game development in XNA.

The first thing you need to do is go into Debug -> Start Performance Analysis.  This profiles your CPU activity and see's what threads are in use and what is doing the most processing.

You also need to factor in a couple of more things:

-You are probably running in debug mode, this means that some of your CPU is being dedicated to VS and to check for exceptions and what not.

-Your code might be inefficient.  I recommend trying to limit the amount of Lists, Arrays, ADT's, and objects created during run time, because that slows it down a lot.  Last time I checked the Game Loop ran 60 times a second so that imagine what a strain it would be to allocate a new List, then garbage collect it, 60 times a second.  It starts adding up.

-I don't know how advanced you are, but read up on parallel threading, or multitasking.
An example would to have your physics engine 1 frames behind your graphics update.

EDIT: I realized you found your mistake but I hope this post can help others.

Comment: The game is still a little slow, and Ill be checking a few more performance bugs, to get it fast again. This is great advice!

Comment: I using "Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone" and I don't see the option "Debug -> Start Performance Analysis". Was this added on a newer version or removed at some point?

Comment: Its only availible in Visual Studio Premium and Visual Studio Ultimate