# Lag when updating a lot of things? XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm currently making a game using C# and XNA, and I've implemented a sort of block feature similar to [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net/game), except from a top down perspective. Adding blocks is implemented through using a list of blocks and their vectors (so that I can re-add all the the blocks when someone tries to load the game). This has been working fine, but I found that (after adding 4 new blocks to the game) updating each block has been causing tremendous amounts of lag.

I've implemented a function that checks if the blocks bounding box is within the viewport bounds here:

```c#
for (int b = 0; b < blocklist.Count; b++)
{
    if (view.Contains((int)blocklist[b].blockposition.X, (int)blocklist[b].blockposition.Y))
    {
        blocklist[b].visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        blocklist[b].visible = false;
    }
}
```

If `visible` equals `true`, the block is drawn, however, I'm still getting a little lag in spite of this, so I was wondering if I could constrict the update method from this:

```c#
foreach (Builder b in blocklist)
{
    b.Update();
}
```

To this:

```c#
foreach (Builder b in blocklist)
{
    if (b.visible == true)
    {
        b.Update();
    }
}
```

Would this ignore updating the blocks if they're not on-screen?

Thanks for any input, and performance tips!

**EDIT:** I've been trying to implement your array idea, but I'm having some issues

```c#
        if (player.Builder == true && player.LMBpressed == true && blockspawnamount >=                                     placeblock && collisionengine.connecting <= 0)
        {
            if (build.BlockID == 1 && menu.open == false)
            {

                position = new Vector2((int)(cursor.cursorPos.X/ 58) * 58, (int)(cursor.cursorPos.Y / 58) * 58);

                blocktex1 = grass1;
                Builder[,] blocks = new Builder[grass1.Width, grass1.Height];
                Builder block = blocks[x,y];

                for (int x = view.Left; x < view.Right; ++x)
                {
                    for (int y = view.Top; y < view.Bottom; ++y)
                    {
                        blocks[x,y].Update();
                    }
                }


                blockpos1.Add(position);


                placeblock = 200.0f;
            }


        }
```

The issue I'm having is that here:

```c#
    Builder block = blocks[x,y];
```

it says the index was out of bounds of the array.

Now to explain how this works. Upon clicking the position is set to be at the cursors position divided by the block textures width (the int 58 in this case) It then adds the block to the list and draws it later. I don't have a separate Blocks class that manages the type of block, however the Builder class controls both the placing and type of block being placed.

**Now here's my question:** Do you add to an array like you usually add to a list? can you then draw it like a list?

**Also:** due to the fact that the Builder class controls the placing of the blocks, I can't remove the position variable, if I do, there will be no position to place the blocks

Comment: I agree with Vaughan Hilts, you'll need to profile your code to find where the bottleneck is. On the face of it though, I can see your function that checks if a box is visible being one probably bottleneck. You're essentially checking every single box always; this means if you have 10,000 boxes, but only 3 are visible, you've still checked all 10,000. Since you essentially have a 2D top-down view, perhaps you can implement a [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or [RTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtree). They'll give you _super-fast_ lookups to find which blocks are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your structure from a list to a `2D Array` ([Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array)) This is IDEAL for what you are doing and you will see a huge increase in performance over using a list.

For example:

```
Builder[,] Blocks = new Builder[WIDTH,HEIGHT];
```

You wont need the position variable in your `Builder` class so you can remove that.

Now when you want to get or set any block, it is like using a grid, instead of a list, so it is very easy to get a specific block

```
Builder Block = Blocks[x,y];
```

Now when you update or draw these blocks, you can introduce a method called culling, what it does it prevent the objects that are off scene from being draw/updated.

```
for (int x = left; x < right; ++x)
{
     for (int y = top; y < bottom; ++y)
     {
          Blocks[x,y].Update()
     } 
}
```

Now your `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` variables will be the edges of your viewport/camera. If you simply want to test this without culling you can just set `left` as 0 and right as `Blocks.GetUpperBound(0);` (0 is width, 1 is height)

Also, Don't try and guess what is wrong, You need to use a profiler to find what is eating up the CPU.

Heres some related problems I had that may help you out.

[Low FPS, What Profiling Application Should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814575/extremely-low-fps-what-profiling-application-should-i-use-to-find-performance-i)

[Performing an Update Tick on tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53422/creating-an-update-tick-on-tiles-for-simulating-growth-of-plants/53441?noredirect=1#comment94411_53441)

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if you updated such a flag yourself in your code somewhere. If you apply logic to set this flag, then of course this will work. If you don't - then such a flag is useless. Profile your code and find your bottleneck - don't guess.