# XNA 2D Tile Based Texture Size

Tags: c#, xna, textures, tile

I am using XNA game studio to make a 2D Sandbox RPG similar to Terraria & Starbound.
I have a great tile system but it still takes over 12-13 ms to draw a whole scene at 1920 x 1200 when the screen is full of tiles.
I have over 15 tile sets currently each one is all together on a 256 x 1024 texture plus each tile set has 6-7 extra tile sets of the same size for rendering the blends with other tiles.
I am wondering if it would make much of a performance difference if I just created a larger texture at load-time and copied all of the blend textures over using `SetData()`.

Is there any performance issues with drawing an 18 x 18 portion of a large texture such as 2048 x 1024 a few hundred times on the screen?

I am using `spritemode.texture` to draw my tiles which already improved the speed a bit but I am trying to shave off a couple more milliseconds.

Comment: Welcome. If you are looking for a specific solution, you could probably share your code, or the part of it that addresses the question (it helps if the code is reproducible).

Answer (score 0):

That number seems quite high, but the only sure way to find it would be to profile it. `SpriteSortMode.Texture` and `Deferred` will be the fastest, some good move there. If you could share a sample of your spritesheets and rendering code that would be nice, I'm not sure why you would need all of that. Using `SourceRectangle` overloads of spritebatch should not effect your draw time, but again, the only way to find out for sure if to [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814575/extremely-low-fps-what-profiling-application-should-i-use-to-find-performance-i) it.

Ofcourse, the less texture swaps the better, so packing everything into 1 texture will be a good idea, and there is a nice [code sample](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_sheet) on MSDN about it.